# Grafana couldn't get metrics from python prometheus (‘no metrics found’)

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a python program running a Prometheus server and I am trying to get its metrics from grafana.
After successfully adding Prometheus data source and setting it as default, when I go to explore page I get ‘No metrics found’ message in the metrics drop-down list.
From grafana container:

- I can curl Prometheus service and get the correct list of metrics
- I made sure that date is in UTC, based on recommendation for other topics

I attempted debugging it through chrome Network tab and I could see using preview that it did receive the correct list of metrics in 4 messages: rules, labels, values, and metadata

Answer (score 0):

Your question would benefit from showing your working; i.e. include the `curl` command and the response; explain how you're running the services|containers etc.

You say "container".

It's possible that the Grafana container is unable to access the host:port of the Python code. If the Prometheus server is bound to a host port, the Grafana container won't be able to access it **unless** the Grafana container is *either* run `--net=host` *or* you're able to provide the container with a resolvable (non-`localhost`) host name to the host.